# Accessing metadata from NestJS controllers

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs, metadata

is there a way to access metadata from controller methods?

For example, I add metadata to a controller class with SetMetadata() - e.g. from a decorator.

I know how to access metadata in a guard. You need to inject reflector and guard.canActivate() has ExecutionContext parameter.

```
canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
  metadata: SomeType = this.reflector.get<EnabledFeatures>(SOME_METADATA_KEY, [context.getClass()]);
}
```

To get metadata I need 2 components: Reflector and ExecutionContext.
I can inject Reflector into controller, but how can I access ExecutionContext from a controller?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we set some metadata on `Controller` with `@SetMetadata` :

```js
@Controller({...})
@SetMetadata('roles', ['admin'])
```

We can have access to it, by creating our [custom param decorator](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators#param-decorators):

```js
export const Roles = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    // get roles metadata from @Controller class
    const roles = Reflect.getMetadata('roles', ctx.getClass());
    return roles;
  },
);
```

And then we can use it on controller's method :

```js
@Get()
getInfo(@Roles() roles): string {
  // roles = ['admin']

  //...
}
```

#### Some notes

###### @SetMetadata not a good practice

Usage of `@SetMetadata` directly is not really a good practice. Prefer to create a specific decorator (for maintenance and readability of code) :

```js
export const SetRoles = (...roles: string[]) => SetMetadata('roles', roles);

...

@Controller({...})
@SetRoles('admin')
export class MyController {...}
```

###### Reflect.getMetadata API vs Injector

Even if `Reflect.getMetadata` is [in fact called](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/3df2932315a86c599cf1a4c0e0d82f56e421a721/packages/core/services/reflector.service.ts) by `Reflector` API of NestJS, it could be changed in the future.
So if we want to deal with only public/documented API of NestJS, we can:

- use a [global guard](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards), which will inject `Injector`,
- get metadata with `ExecutionContext`
- and then set result in `Request` instance.

An other custom param decorator will retrieve data from `Request` and return it.

More complicated, but without using direct call to `Reflect.getMetadata` API.